# MySQL Optimize Table script

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am in the process of upgrading our AWS Aurora RDS cluster from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0. During the upgrade of the cluster, the process failed, and according to AWS, they recommended we run Optimize Table on a number of DB tables before proceeding again. I was able to generate a list of tables that need to be optimized by running a script from AWS, but there are over 1200 tables that need this to be run on. I am not very experienced with SQL scripting, but I have used Powershell and Bash scripting before many times.

What is the best way to script this out, so I can provide a list of tables in a text file or a db table then run Optimize Table on each row or line.

I have done similar scripts in Bash or Powershell as For Each loops and have the tables listed in a text file, but I am not sure how to do a similar process in SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarity, my edit is because T-SQL is the dialect used by SQL Server (and Sybase), not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Output list of tables formatted into OPTIMIZE TABLE statements:

```
mysql -B -N -e "select concat('optimize table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') 
  from information_schema.tables where table_type='BASE TABLE' AND ..." > myscript.sql
```

Add any conditions you want where I put `...`, to filter the tables you want to list. For example: `AND TABLE_SCHEMA='myschema'`.

Run that result as an SQL script:

```
mysql -e "source myscript.sql"
```

(I omitted options for `--hostname`, `--user`, and `--password` or any other options you may need to use to connect to your instance. I usually put these into ~/.my.cnf anyway.)